# Error with copyValuesToRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to take a form input that has a date plus a field indicating the number of days in a range. The date is entered on the form as `mm/dd/yyyy` and number of days is a number from 1-7.

I am taking the new row in the forms spreadsheet and duplicating it N times, N being the number of days in the range.

I am then trying to modify one field in each of the duplicated records which is a date in YYYY-MM-DD format by adding one day to the field.  When I try to overwrite the one field I get:

> TypeError: Cannot find function copyValuesToRange in object 2015-11-05.(line 46,file"")

The code I am using is bits and pieces of code I have found through this forum with some modifications:

```
function onSubmit() {
// Sheet to which form submits
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FormInput");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// Determine the from date
  var date = (sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4).getValue()); 

// READ THE NUMBER OF NEW ROWS FROM THE DESIGNATED COLUMN IN "FormInput"
  var N = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();

// Sheet to which we will write
  var sheetRec = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("UpdatedFormInput");
  var lastColumn = sheetRec.getLastColumn();
  var lastRowT = sheetRec.getLastRow();
  var lastRowB = sheetRec.getLastRow();

// Create N new Rows by copying in the template row N times
  var Template = sheetRec.getRange(2, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  for (j = 1; j <=N; j++) {
      Template.copyTo(sheetRec.getRange(lastRowT + j, 1));
  }

  var Val1 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1);
  var Val2 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2);
  var Val3 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3);
  var Val4 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4);
  var Val5 = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);

  Val1.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 1, 1, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
  Val2.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 2, 2, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
  Val3.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 3, 3, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
  Val4.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 4, 4, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);
  Val5.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 5, 5, lastRowT + 1, lastRowT + N);

// modify the date field in each of the new rows starting from the second new row 
  var startrowT = lastRowT + 2;
  var endrowT = lastRowT + N;

// Copy new data values into the rows
  for (j = 1; j <N; j++) {
     var result = new Date(date.getTime()+j*(24*3600*1000));
     Val4 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(result), "GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd");
// I am trying to copy my new date, (current date + 1), into a cell in multiple rows, column 4
// the utility is returning a string and the receiving field is a date
// getting error "TypeError: Cannot find function copyValuesToRange in object 2015-11-05.(line 46,file"")
     Val4.copyValuesToRange(sheetRec, 4, 4, startrowT, 1);
// getting error "TypeError: Cannot find function copyValuesToRange in object 2015-11-05.(line 46,file"")
     startrowT = startrowT + 1;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why I am getting the error.

Comment: You are overwriting Val4 with a Date Object on Line 43.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach A string, actually - the output of `Utilities.formatDate()`. But regardless, Val4 is **not** a Range object.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As [Samantha](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/SwIuouNeblw/rTTJq0WyNwAJ) explained, you can use instead of .copyValuesToRange() the function .getRange().setValues()

Since I don't fully understand the ranges you're pulling, I'll show you what I ended up doing when I encountered the same problem. 
I was trying to copy headers from one sheet to another:

```
     // First define the sheet that you're pulling data from ("dataSheet")

     var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var dataSheet = file.getSheetByName("name");

     // Then define the new sheet that you're pulling data to,
     // in my case I look to see if the secondary sheet ("updateSheet") 
     // already exists, otherwise I insert a new sheet, 
     // and define its name.

     var updateSheet = file.getSheetByName("Update Data from " + name);

     var updateSheet = updateSheet || file.insertSheet();
     updateSheet.setName("Update Data from " + name);

     // Then I was looking to copy the headers of my first sheet
     // and copy those to my second sheet.

     var shortHeaders = dataSheet.getRange('A1:M1');
     var headersValues = shortHeaders.getValues();

     updateSheet.getRange("A1:M1").setValues(headersValues);
```

Hopefully this converts to what you're trying to do as well! If not, please ask me, maybe with some open discussion we can figure it out together how it can be applied to your data.